# Optimum way to perform a bland altman analysis using R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to produce a Bland-Altman plot using GGplot2?

I have looked at using methcomp but cant seem to get my data into a Meth object

```
library(MethComp)

comp <- read.csv("HIVVL.csv")
com <- data.frame(comp)
co <- Meth(com)

with(co, BA.plot(Qiagen, Abbot))
```

keep running into the error

```
comp <- read.csv("HIVVL.csv")
com <- data.frame(comp)
co <- Meth(com)
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , meth) : undefined columns selected
```

a print of com looks somthing like this

```
    Abbot  Qiagen
1   66000   66057
2   40273   73376
3   13818   14684
4   53328  195509
5    8369   25000
6   89833  290000 
7     116     219
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read `?Meth`? It is looking for columns named `meth` and `item` in your data, which don't exist (see my example below).

Also, the step `com <- data.frame(comp)` is not doing anything different than `com <- comp`.  `read.csv` already returns a `data.frame`.

```
d <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10)

Meth(d)
# Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , meth) : undefined columns selected

Meth(d, meth='x')
# Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , item) : undefined columns selected

Meth(d, meth='x', item='y')
# The following variables from the dataframe
# "d" are used as the Meth variables:
# meth: x 
# item: y  
#    y: y 
#        #Replicates
# Method          1 #Items #Obs: 10 Values:  min med max
#     1           1      1        1            1   1   1
#     2           1      1        1            2   2   2
#     3           1      1        1            3   3   3
#     4           1      1        1            4   4   4
#     5           1      1        1            5   5   5
#     6           1      1        1            6   6   6
#     7           1      1        1            7   7   7
#     8           1      1        1            8   8   8
#     9           1      1        1            9   9   9
#     10          1      1        1           10  10  10
```